# is_taxonomy is deprecated. What's the alternative?

Tags: taxonomy, register-taxonomy

Now that `is_taxonomy($taxonomy)` function deprecated how do I know if a taxonomy exist? What's the alternative?

On a second note, the codex for `wp_insert_term()` says that if the taxonomy does not exist, an error is fired. Here, the "if taxonomy exists" part is ambiguous to me. Does that mean if the taxonomy has currently been registered with the registered_taxonomy or does that mean there is at least one term in the `wp_term_taxonomy()` table that's been associated with that taxonomy?

And my 3rd question final question is how do I catch an error when an error is raised by the `wp_insert_term()` function?

Would this work?

```
if (list($term_id,$taxonomy_id) = wp_insert_term(...)):
else:
  //error here?
endif;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Codex page for [`is_taxonomy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_taxonomy)

> This function is deprecated as of Version 3.0. Please use [taxonomy_exists](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/taxonomy_exists) instead.

`wp_insert_term` uses `taxonomy_exists` to check if the taxonomy exists. This means if the taxonomy is a *registered* taxonomy. (It would be odd if `wp_insert_term` only you allowed to add a term to taxonomies with existing terms :) )

To catch an error you can use [`is_wp_error`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_wp_error). E.g.

```
$result = wp_insert_term(...);
if ( is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
   $error_string = $result->get_error_message();
   echo '<div id="message" class="error"><p>' . $error_string . '</p> </div>';
}else{
   list($term_id,$taxonomy_id) = $result;
 }
```

Comment: Cool & thanks Stephen. What do you mean by "It would be odd if wp_insert_term only you allowed to add a term to taxonomies with existing terms".

Comment: Also, can you address the error checking part of my question too?

Comment: Done :). What I meant was that `wp_insert_term` is used to create taxonomy terms and it should be able to do that even if a taxonomy doesn't currently have any terms.

Comment: Let's continue on this here > http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48572/missing-term-id-and-term-taxonomy-id-when-adding-a-term-using-wp-insert-term-f