# Missing term_id and term_taxonomy_id when adding a term using wp_insert_term() function

Tags: taxonomy, terms

Check the line;
    list($term_id,$taxonomy_id) = $result 
in the code snippet below. ( towards the bottom ). 
Why am I missing the term_id & the $taxonomy_id when I echo their values? 
Aren't they supposed to be populated by the wp_insert them?

```
$term_name = 'Uncategorized';
$term_slug = sanitize_title('Uncategorized', 'Default category slug');
$term_taxonomy = 'category';
$term_description = $term_slug . " desc here.. ";
$term_parentID = 0;

if ( is_term( $term_name , $term_taxonomy ) ):
    echo "this term exists!";
    die;
else:
    //echo "This terms does not exist!";
    //echo "<pre>";
    //global $wp_taxonomies;
    //print_r ($wp_taxonomies);
    //echo "</pre>";
    if (taxonomy_exists($term_taxonomy)):
        //insert the term into the wp_terms
        $args = array(
                            'description' => $term_description,
                            'slug' => $term_slug,
                            'parent' => $term_parentID 
                        );  

        $result = wp_insert_term($term_name, $term_taxonomy, $args);

        if ( is_wp_error( $result ) ):
            $error_string = $result->get_error_message();
            echo '<div id="message" class="error"><p>' . $error_string . '</p> </div>';
        else:
            list($term_id,$taxonomy_id) = $result;
            echo "<p>The term <i>{$term_name}</i> under the <i>{$term_taxonomy}</i> taxonomy has been added into the <i>wp_terms & wp_term_taxonomy<i> tables. The Term ID is {$term_id} and the related taxonomy ID is {$term_taxonomy_id}.";
            //outputs as The term Uncategorized under the category taxonomy has been added into the wp_terms & wp_term_taxonomy tables. The Term ID is and the related taxonomy ID is .
        endif;                          
    else:
        echo "<p>{$term_taxonomy} does not exist. we cannot add this $term. Please use the register_taxonomy function to register this taxonomy. ";
    endif;
endif;
```

Comment: You should use [`term_exists`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists) rather than the depreciated `is_term`.

Comment: I just ran the above code and it works fine: I get 'this term exists' (as expected).

Comment: But do you get the term_id of the term that exists? Just echo the $term_ID. I get blank. My echo outputs this;             //outputs as The term Uncategorized under the category taxonomy has been added into the wp_terms & wp_term_taxonomy tables. The Term ID is and the related taxonomy ID is .

Comment: Interestingly, when I did print_r on $results, I'm seeing Array ( [term_id] => 1 [term_taxonomy_id] => 1 )
But then why does list() function is failing to assign the term_id into $term_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of the php function `list`. If successful, `wp_insert_term` returns something of the form:

```
array(2) { ["term_id"]=> int(307) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(325) }
```

You can't use [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) with this as `list` only works for numerical arrays. Instead try [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) instead:

```
extract($result);
echo "<p>The term <i>{$term_name}</i> under the <i>{$term_taxonomy}</i> taxonomy has been added into the <i>wp_terms & wp_term_taxonomy<i> tables. The Term ID is {$term_id} and the related taxonomy ID is {$term_taxonomy_id}.";
```

Comment: I wrapped the whole thing into a library function.

Answer (score 0):

```
//------get term/taxonomy data

$term_name = 'Uncategorized';
$term_slug = 'Default category slug';  //this gets sanitized by the blp_wordpress_insert_term function!
$term_taxonomy = 'category';
$term_description = $term_name . " desc here.. ";
$term_parentID = 0;

//------byref stuff: library function will populate them in return

$term_id = null; 
$term_taxonomy_id = null; 
$term_error = null; 

//------call the library function

if (blp_wordpress_insert_term($term_name,$term_slug,$term_taxonomy,$term_description,$term_parentID,$term_id,$term_taxonomy_id,$term_error)):
    echo "<p>" , "The term <i>{$term_name}</i> under the <i>{$term_taxonomy}</i> taxonomy has been added into the <i>wp_terms & wp_term_taxonomy<i> tables. The Term ID is {$term_id} and the related taxonomy ID is {$term_taxonomy_id}.";
else:
    echo "<p>" , $term_error;
    die;
endif;

//-----------------------------here is the library function

function blp_wordpress_insert_term($term_name,$term_slug,$term_taxonomy,$term_description,$term_parentID,&$term_id,&$term_taxonomy_id,&$term_error){

    /*

    inserts a term under the given taxonomy and returns the term_id and term_taxonomy_id byref if everything is cool/

    it also returns as TRUE or FALSE as a whole depending on a proper entry

    it also populates the $term_error variable - passed byref if an error occurs

    TO DO: validate the passed parentid to see if its a valid ID 

    */

    $term_slug = sanitize_title($term_name, $term_slug);

    if ( term_exists( $term_name , $term_taxonomy ) ):
        $term_error = "ERROR: The term ({$term_name}) already exists!";
        return false;

    else:

        if (taxonomy_exists($term_taxonomy)): //insert the term into the wp_terms

            $args = array(
                                'description' => $term_description,
                                'slug' => $term_slug,
                                'parent' => $term_parentID 
                            );  

            $result = wp_insert_term($term_name, $term_taxonomy, $args);
            //print_r ($result); // Array ( [term_id] => 1 [term_taxonomy_id] => 1 )

            if ( is_wp_error( $result ) ):
                $term_error = "ERROR: " . $result->get_error_message();
                return false;
            else:
                $term_id = $result['term_id'];
                $term_taxonomy_id = $result['term_taxonomy_id']; 
                return true;
            endif;                          
        else:
            $term_error = "ERROR: The taxonomy {$term_taxonomy} does not exist. blp_wordpress_insert_term cannot add a term when its associated taxonomy missing. Use the <i>register_taxonomy</i> function to register the taxonomy <i>{$term_taxonomy}. ";
            return false;
        endif;
    endif;
```

}